# Jquery pass ajax call with post attribute

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Checked several topics here on stack overflow and the jquery documentation but still getting stuck.

I basically want this to post (with ajax/jquery) to update a div's content.

```
function loadSubCats(value)
{
    $.post("load_sub_cats.php",
        data: { "catid": value },
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            function(data) {
        $('#sub_categories').html("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
}
```

But im getting no responses what so ever. The page contains the sub_categories div, and this is called onclick for a form event.

```
<select name='cselect3' onChange='loadSubCats(this.value)' class='e1'>
```

So basically, it should past the value of the field (cselect3) and load_sub_cats.php should just echo $_POST[catid];  thats it. But im getting zero activity on it so it think its something simple i've screwed up.

Comment: Did you try to inspect the request? Chrome Dev tools or Firebug? What do you get?

Comment: 1 error, Uncaught ReferenceError: loadSubCats is not defined

Comment: which means your function "loadSubCats" containing the `$.post` never gets called.

Comment: look at the script included/written above loadSubCats function. May be there is some error and so loadSubCats function is not found

Comment: @MichaelClarke have you tried my answer? I've corrected your code.

Comment: We need to see where/how you call "loadSubCats" to detect the error per your note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem with `$.post` syntax. Here's how it should be:

```
function loadSubCats(value)
{
    $.post("load_sub_cats.php",{ "catid": value },
            function(data) {
        $('#sub_categories').html("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
}
```

as simple as it is.

Comment: That loads the other page, but the how do i use the value it passed? $_GET, $POST both dont contain it

Comment: use $_POST["catid"] should get you the data passed by the above function.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the syntax of `$.post` and `$.ajax` which are different. If you want to use the object syntax then call `$.ajax`, because `$.post` takes its arguments as a simple un-named list.

```
function loadSubCats(value)
{
   $.ajax({
        url : "load_sub_cats.php",
        data: { "catid": value },
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#sub_categories').html("Data Loaded: " + data);
        }
    });
}
```

You could also directly attach the `change` event instead, of inline and do away with the `loadSubCats()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=cselect3]').change(function(){
       $.ajax({
            url : "load_sub_cats.php",
            data: { "catid": $(this).val() },
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#sub_categories').html("Data Loaded: " + data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this it didnt resolve the problem, still getting the ncaught ReferenceError: loadSubCats is not defined  and no output on screen.

Comment: Where you are placing the `loadSubCats()` function? Put it in the global scope, not in a a `$(document).ready` or any other closure.

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadSubCats(value)
{
$.post("load_sub_cats.php",
    {  catid: value }, 
     function(data) {
     $('#sub_categories').html("Data Loaded: " + data); }
     );
}
```

You send catid not "catid"

Answer (score -1):

two things:

you are using type in post which is not required.

Even after removing it is not working just try to alert it-

```
function loadSubCats(value)
{
    $.post("load_sub_cats.php",
        data: { "catid": value },
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            function(data) {
          alert(data)
         $('#sub_categories').html("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
}
```

By alert you will come to know -
1) if there is any php error it will alert that, 
2) If php is working fine that it will alert with your values.

updating my post as per latest comments:
Try to  use like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.e1').change(function() {
        $.post("load_sub_cats.php",
        data: { "catid": value },
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            function(data) {
          alert(data)
         $('#sub_categories').html("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });  
  })
});
```

Comment: Still receiving the same error and no output. Have checked the file receiving and there are no errors on it.

Comment: if you are using $(document).ready() than it will be not same error. And if error is same than how you are checking PHP file output?